# Object Oriented C like code - Identification of caller without parameters

Tags: c, oop

If I have this setup:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NEW_FOO ((foo_t*)malloc(sizeof(foo_t)))

void foo_func(void);

typedef struct {
    void (*foo) (void);
} foo_t;

int main(void) {
    foo_t *a = NEW_FOO;
    foo_t *b = NEW_FOO;
    a->foo = foo_func;
    b->foo = foo_func;
    a->foo();
    b->foo();
}

void foo_func(void) {
    // determine wheter a or b was called?
}
```

Can I then find out, wheter `a` or `b` was the caller of `foo_func`, strictly without a parameter like `self`, `this`, `...`?

The return address should be on the stack, so you should be able to identify the caller somehow, no?

I thought of a possible approach (it builds upon the idea above): The first time the `foo_func` is called (maybe through an initialization function, but let's leave that out to keep it simple) through `a->foo()`, store the address of struct `a` in some sort of array of pointers, I would assume. Same with `b->foo()`. Then, anytime that `a->foo()` or `b->foo()` is called, you would compare the address of the caller struct with the contents in the array to identify wheter it was `a` or `b` that called `foo_func()`.

It's just that I have no Idea if and/or how that is possible, so if anyone of you could help me with this, I would be very glad!

Comment: Could you give some more background why you would need this? The most obvious and safe solution is by adding a (void*) argument and pass it to the function as context, even if you strictly want to avoid this.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't, unless you pass `foo_func()` more information.

Comment: Mostly out of curiousity and mainly for my free-time-projects. Secondly I want to learn more about C, and every bit helps. Thirdly, the additional argument is not that beautiful to look at, let's be honest.

Comment: Well, if we are really being honest, C is not that beautiful a language... at least not if you want to do things it wasn't designed for - and if you want to _really_ emulate OOP principles like `this`/`self` in C, you need to write all the boilerplate that the language itself doesn't provide, such as adding an explicit `this`/`self` pointer to every method declaration and call. You can't shortcut like you want to here. A `struct` containing function pointers isn't a full implementation of OOP, and this proves that.

Comment: Except from the additional writing effort, I don’t see why the additional argument is not beautiful - as you say. That’s a common pattern in C in e.g callbacks to refer to the original context the callback was registered to. As stated above, in C you need to write stuff that is hidden in a lot of modern OOP languages.

Comment: in `C` you can hide function parameters having the default values. so the only solution is `void foo_func(const foo_t *this);` and `a->foo(a)` But if you want OOP IMO the worst thing is to imitate it in C. You have a C++ and no tricks needed

Comment: @P__J__ Maybe so, but OOP in plain C is absolutely commonplace. It's the backbone of GTK and all its supporting libraries, for example. Moreover, I often work in embedded environments where the choices are C or machine code; C++ is not ubiquitous.

Comment: @KevinBoone then one parameter more should not be a problem. Or if it is a problem - OOP language instead.

Comment: @P__J__ It _isn't_ a problem, and my answer attempts to convince the OP of that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're annoyed about the unsightliness of constructions like:

```
a->foo (a, arg0, arg1);
b->bar (b, arg0);
```

Unfortunately, the style of programming you've adopted does force this style on you, if you want to implement a simulation of polymorphic methods. Maybe you can implement a set of macros so you can write something like:

```
METHOD_CALL2 (foo, a, arg0, arg1);
METHOD_CALL1 (bar, b, arg0);
```

and so not have to repeat the "object" names `a`, `b`, etc., in the call. I've seen this done as well but, in my view, it doesn't look any prettier, and I'm sure it's no more maintainable.

As this is C, not C++, in the end you're going to have to have *some* way to pass your equivalent of `this` to the "methods" in your implementation. You might be able to disguise it with macros and variable-length argument lists, but it's going to have to happen somehow.

But why worry? This is idiomatic C code -- every application and library that takes an object-oriented approach to C will be using constructions of the form you want to avoid. People will understand what you're doing. Trying to disguise it will not make your code easier to follow, I suspect.

Comment: Yes the macro thing is really weird in this case IMO. I was just curious if there would be some hidden, sneaky way of tracing back the caller (I'm pretty sure in assembler that is possible), because C is so "plain stupid" and that may be also why I really like it :P

Comment: @rphii -- I'm not sure how this situation can arise in assembly language programming. What would a structure whose members are function pointers amount to in assembly?

Comment: to be honest, I don't know much about assembly, but isn't that like the ultimate thing, in terms of flexibility?